# invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘foo*&’ from an rvalue of type ‘foo*’?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Imagine this simple code, why does it get compile error?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class foo{
public:
    int *b;
    foo(int a) {
        b = NULL;
    }
};

void bar(foo *&a) {
    cout << "OK?" << endl;
}

int main() {
    foo a(2);
    bar(&a);
    return 0;
}
```

I know I can use `bar(foo *a)` but why with & symbol it doesn't work and how can I make it work?

Comment: The compiler error is quite explicit as to *why* (the rvalue is from `&a`). But what do you mean by "make it work"? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: what adjustment should I do in my code so that it won't get compilation-error?  @juanchopanza

Comment: @Bat you answered your own question (one way to make it work is to use `bar(foo *a)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work, change `main` to:

```
foo *p = &a;
bar(p);
```

The use of an lvalue reference (`foo* &`) means that the argument must be an lvalue.  `p` is an lvalue because it is the name of a variable.  `&a` is a prvalue.

---

If you want to change `bar` but not `main` then you could use any of `foo *a`, `foo * const &a`, or `foo * && a`, which can be initialized with an rvalue.

Comment: Do you think "lvalue"/"prvalue" is going to mean much to the OP?

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet if it doesn't, they can read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3601748/1505939) or whatever.  It's not really possible to provide a short but complete summary .